# sum number values from localStorage while looping

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I found the same examples over and over about how to sum values but I haven't been able to use it for myself.  I have two sets of data saved in localStorage.  The first values for both keys are numbers which I want to add together.  I found many .each functions that do the looping but I want to do it while looking through the key/value pairs, have a variable contain the sum as the key/value pairs loop.  So here's what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(localStorage.length > 0){
    for (var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++){
        var sum = 0;
        var key = localStorage.key(i); 
        var val = localStorage.getItem(key);
        var valu = val.split("*");
        alert (valu[0]); //alerts twice 130 and 160
        sum += valu[0]; //didn't do anything
        sum += parseInt(valu[0]); //also didn't work
        alert (sum);
    }
}
});
```

So the two values are 130 and 160 and they alert out as the function loops...so how can I add them and have like a running total as it loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `var sum = 0;` outside the loop, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(localStorage.length > 0){
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i=0, len=localStorage.length; i<len; i++){
            var key = localStorage.key(i); 
            var val = localStorage.getItem(key);
            var valu = val.split("*");
            alert (valu[0]); //alerts twice 130 and 160
            sum += parseInt(valu[0]); //also didn't work
            alert (sum);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You may also wish to add some error handling in there, such that it doesn't break if `valu[0]` is not a number.

Comment: Thank!!!  That worked...man, I was close.  Thanks for the advice...the value in localStorage is controlled by me...it's like a shopping cart so I set the value and when the user clicks to buy, the number gets inserted.  So maybe I can do without error handling?

Comment: Maybe. I, personally, would be very wary when doing anything to do with a shopping cart with a technology which can be controlled by the user. For example a while back I came across a site where the item and price was submitted using JavaScript. Problem was that the price was also set with JS, so you could edit the code, using dev tools, so that you bought 100 of something for free. With the right knowledge and expertise applied, I don't see the harm. Just saying I would be cautious.

Comment: Damn...I guess you're right...so I should probably stick to mysql?  That has a lot more protection against things like this

Comment: well you should just make sure that, whatever technologies you use, it is secure. It is ok to use JS - just make sure you clean the data when it gets to the server (so no SQL injection is possible, for example) and that you only refer to products by id - so the server then fetches the price as and when a request is made. If the user wants to alter the number using dev tools, so be it, but at least you can then multiply the number by the correct price.